# Increase size of file path pane in windows search?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, search, windows-search

In normal file explorer, you can resize columns by dragging them around using the little tab marker type things:

[image]

In windows search, you can't do this for some reason! There are no tab markers to drag. When the file paths are long enough to be truncated, this becomes a problem. Is there any way to see the full file path? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Works fine here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the search results open up and start populating, change the view from "Content" to "Details":

[image]

You'll then be able to adjust the columns as in your first screenshot.

Comment: I would vote you up but I lack the required reputation haha. Thanks so much!